# Dropping a database does not free diskspace

Tags: mongodb

I have mongodb set up with a single config server and 5 shards.
After successfully dropping a database using `db.dropDatabase()` command, 
`show dbs` still lists the database and the disk space isn't freed.
Moreover, if I again connect to the database and start inserting, the database is build up from whatever disk space was used earlier even though the data before prior to dropping the database is no longer accessible..

Comment: Which version of MongoDB are you using?

Comment: The latest version 2.2.1...

Comment: Are you trying `db.dropDatabase()` form the `mongos` shell, or one of the shards?  Can you confirm which nodes have the db files removed, as at least some of the five shard nodes should have no files for that db in their dbpath.

Comment: Yes, I fired `db.dropDatabase()` from the `mongos` shell.

Comment: Which nodes still have the files for that DB in their DB path?  All of them?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have that information anymore because I had to use the database again.

Comment: Does dropping any new database result in the same behaviour?

Comment: I figured I was getting network transport errors of some sort while connecting to one of the nodes whenever I issued a dropDatabase command. This seemed to cause the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Did you switched to database before dropping?

```
use database_to_drop
db.dropDatabase()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you were having connection issues between your `mongos` and the shards when you issued the `dropDatabase()` command, then you could have had this issue.  This would have been seen in the shell with something similar to the following:

```
{
    "errmsg" : "exception: socket exception [CONNECT_ERROR] for <shard>",
    "code" : 11002,
    "ok" : 0
}
```

Since the connection could not be established between the `mongos` and the node that made up the shard, or the Primary for that shard if it is a replica set, then the database could not be removed.  The same will be true if the shard has no Primary, since the shard would then be read-only.